# Explain collection_select in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})public
```

for e.g.

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

In this helper - Please explain, What is `object` and `method` in detail? Is `:post` a model name and `:author_id` a fieldname in a model or are they tag name.

can they be anything I want, not necessarily `:post` and `author_id`, instead `:post123` or `auth_id`. Will it be perfectly ok?

Please explain be in detail. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can give a brief explanation

**`:post`** - The object you are manipulating. In this case, it's a Post object.

**`:author_id`** - The field that is populated when the Post is saved.

And they are supposed to be like that.you can't replace those with any `strings` or `symbols`.

I think you also need this

**`Author.all`** - The array you are working with.

**`:id`** - The value that is stored in the database. In terms of HTML, this is the  tag's value parameter

**`:name_with_initial`**- The output that the user sees in the pull-down menu. This is the value between the `<option>` tags.

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
collection_select(
    :post, # field namespace 
    :author_id, # field name
    # result of this two params will be: <select name="post[author_id]">...

    # then you should specify some collection or array of rows.
    # It can be Author.where(..).order(..) or someting like that. 
    # In you example it is:
    Author.all, 

    # then you should specify methods for generating options
    :id, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as key
    :name_with_initial, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as value

    # as a result, every option will be generated by the following rule: 
    # <option value=#{author.id}>#{author.name_with_initial}</option>
    # 'author' is row of collection or array

    :prompt => true # then you can specify some params. You can find them in doc.
)
```

answered here [Can someone explain collection_select to me in clear, simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms) by alexkv  (This link should help you to get explanation.)