# Assigning id's from another table to input using nested forms in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, many-to-many

I'm a few weeks in to my first experience with Rails / web development in general and have come across a snag I can't seem to find on overflow or work out. I feel that I'm almost there but not quite...

I'm developing a staff site for a charity, and need to categorize new staff members in order to assign privileges to each of them. Currently, I have a staff new view that creates new staff members, and have a nested form for type in it to add the staff's department at the same time. However, at the moment a new department is generated for every new member of staff. So if I created 2 staff with department "Admin", I end up with 2 Admin departments with separate type_id's instead of them being assigned to the same. How do I assign a staff's type/department as I create it in the form, assuming the departments already exist. In the console I could do this:

```
s = Staff.create(staff_name: "John", staff_email: "John@example.com", password: "asdsadsad")
t = Type.create(department: "Admin")
s.types << t
```

So far my models for staff and types(categories) look like this (irrelevant parts removed), in which I've added accepts_nested_attributes_for:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :staff_types
  has_many :types, through: :staff_types
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :types
  validates :staff_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 50}
  has_secure_password
end

class StaffType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :staff
  belongs_to :type
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :department, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 25 }
  has_many :staff_types
  has_many :staffs, through: :staff_types
end
```

My staff controller, in which i've whitelisted the type variables, is as follows:

```
class StaffsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_staff, only: [:edit, :update, :show]

  def new
    @staff = Staff.new
    1.times { @staff.types.build}
  end 

  def create
    @staff = Staff.new(staff_params)
    if @staff.save
      flash[:success] = "Your account has been created successfully"
      redirect_to staff_path(@staff)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def staff_params
    params.require(:staff).permit(:staff_name, :staff_email, types_attributes: [:id, :department])
  end
end
```

And finally my view is the following, in which I've embedded the nested form in my form_for helper:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="well col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
     <%= form_for @staff do |f| %>

       <%= f.label :staff_name %>
       <%= f.text_field :staff_name %>

       <%= f.label :staff_email %>
       <%= f.email_field :staff_email %>

       <%= f.label :password %>
       <%= f.password_field :password %>

       <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

       <%= f.fields_for :types, @staff.types do |types_form| %>
         <%= types_form.label :department %>
         <%= types_form.text_field :department %>
       <% end %>

       <%= f.submit(@staff.new_record? ? "Submit Profile" : "Submit Edited Profile", class: "btn btn-success") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason a new record is created every time you submit a new staff member is because you don't actually let your controller know that the staff member's type could be an existing type. So now the question is, what is the best way to go about doing this EDIT THIS SENTENCE

**Method #1: Choose staff member types in a multi-select**

If you have a set number of types, you've already inserted them, and you don't need to change them, then you can use a multi-select. To do so, replace the below code in your code...

```
<%= f.fields_for :types, @staff.types do |types_form| %>
  <%= types_form.label :department %>
  <%= types_form.text_field :department %>
<% end %>
```

...with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :type_ids, Type.all, :id, :department,
    { selected: @staff.type_ids }, { multiple: true, size: Type.all.size } %>
```

And then, in your controller, change your `staff_params` method to:

```
def staff_params
  params.require(:staff).permit(:staff_name, :staff_email, type_ids: [])
end
```

Using this method, you'll be able to select multiple types for each staff member out of all possible types. Assuming you don't need to create a type when you create a staff member, I'd recommend going forward with this member.

You can also use checkboxes rather than a multi-select, but I won't cover that in this answer. You can read about check boxes [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

**Method #2: Determine which types are new in your controller**

If you'd like to keep the ability to type in a staff member's type, it'll be a bit trickier, but I think you can keep all of your logic in the `create` method of your controller. Currently, in that method, you save a staff member as soon as you grab the parameters for it. What you can do first is check if any of the types passed are new (i.e. the staff member hasn't yet been associated to that type), and then if at least one is, check if each is an existing type. Update your `create` method to read:

```
def create
  @staff = Staff.assign_attributes(staff_params)

  @staff.staff_types.each_with_index do |staff_type, index|
    if (type = Type.find_by(department: staff_type.type.department)).present?
      @staff.staff_type[index].assign_attribute(:id, type.id)
    end
  end

  if @staff.save
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been created successfully"
    redirect_to staff_path(@staff)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I should note that there is probably a better way to do this, and hopefully this answer encourages someone to post a better one, but this answer should work for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you @Joe, the first method worked wonderfully. As which sections of the site users are allowed to see and what actions they can perform will depend on their department, there will only be a finite list of departments created at the instance the site goes live. Furthermore, only an Admin user will have access to the staff new view anyway. For anyone reading this who like me wasn't sure how `collection_select` worked, see this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms)

Comment: Hey, @Joe, by any chance is there a way to use a drop down menu instead of a  list (I've tried removing the multiple option, or setting the size to 1, but it no longer seems to work after that). 

Also is there a way to select more than one option?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can really have a multi-select drop down. Is that what you're looking for? Also, with `multiple: true`, you should be able to select multiple types. Is this not the case?

Comment: Ah no sorry, I meant the two to be separate, just for future knowledge. So just a single select drop down. 

And for the multi-select, It is indeed! I'm currently switching between a windows work laptop, a mac at home and a ubuntu based cloud environment for most development, so appeared to have just been holding down the wrong key for multi-select in my befuddled state earlier! Slowly losing it over the weekend it seems. Thanks again