# Rails select from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, select

Can somebody explain this ? , it is from ruby guides

```
<%= collection_select(:person, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

I have an attachment model, I want to select its version with combobox when I create an object, and also I want a new version option.

> here what attachment has

```
def change
create_table :attachments do |t|
  t.string :filename
  t.attachment :file
  t.string :version
  t.text :description
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

> UPDATE:

```
<%= f.collection_select( :version,  Attachment.where.not(version: nil), :version, :version) %>
```

it is working like that, but I don't understand,

Comment: Try this - `<%= collection_select(:object, : attachment_id, Attachment.all, :id, :version) %>`

Comment: it said **undefined method `attachment_id'**, and I think the object is :attachment ? from  **<%= form_for(@attachment) do |f| %>**

Comment: sorry I realized know I didn't f.collection_select, I handle it now, but I don't know how to add a new version option to write something different

Comment: by the way ı handle it but I still not understand how it works

Comment: `<%= collection_select(:f, :attachment_id, Attachment.all, :id, :version) %>` I thought it is working but the objects have a null version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to avoid the `nil` value of the `version`:

```
collection_select(:f, :attachment_id, Attachment.where.not(version: nil), :id, :version)
```

#### Explanation of How collection_select Works:

```
collection_select(
    :f, # field namespace 
    :attachment_id, # field name
    # result of these two params will be: <select name="f[attachment_id]">...

    # then you should specify some collection or array of rows.
    # In your example it is:
    Attachment.where.not(version: nil)

    # Then, you should specify methods for generating options
    :id, # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as key
    :version # this is name of method that will be called for every row, result will be set as value
)
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms) and [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

check accepted answer from this thread for explanation on how collection_select works: [Can someone explain collection_select to me in clear, simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms)

In this select:

```
<%= collection_select(:f, :attachment_id, Attachment.all, :id, :version) %>
```

you display all versions from already created attachments, so if attachments table is empty you will get null

Comment: I can see the options like 1.version, 2.version, etc. I can select but it is not working, the object I just created has null version

Comment: if you use strong parameters check if you permit f[:attachment_id], also consider using select_tag instead of collection_select as it's sending single selected item, not an array of them

Comment: I don't understand what f[attachment_id] is, I just want to choose new attachments version from combobox, I handle it like that `<%= collection_select(:f, :attachment_id, Attachment.all, :id, :version) %>` .But I don't know how to write new version instead of choosing from combobox