# Change the option selected on collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to change the option that is selected on collection_select on my form in rails.

My code look like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :course_type_id, CourseType.where(:deleted => false), :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control  m-b', :selected => @course_template.course_type.name } %>
```

However the option selected always shows the first one and never changes unless the user selects a different option.

The resulting html looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control  m-b" selected="selected" name="course[course_type_id]" id="course_course_type_id">
    <option value="1">Driving</option>
    <option value="2">Pratical</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `@course_template.course_type.name`?

Comment: The value of `@course_template.course_type.name` it's `Pratical` in this case

Comment: Can you try `:selected => @course_template.course_type.id`?

Comment: I also tried with the id like this `<%= f.collection_select :course_type_id, CourseType.where(:deleted => false), :id, :name, {}, {class: 'form-control  m-b', selected: @course_template.course_type.id } %>` but the result is the same.

Comment: Please try: `<%= f.collection_select :course_type_id, CourseType.where(:deleted => false), :id, :name, { :selected => @course_template.course_type.id }, {class: 'form-control  m-b' } %>`

Comment: It's working thanks ;)

Comment: Adding it as an answer, with explanation.

Comment: Ooh sorry Ustav I beat you to it. @InesM please accept Ustav's answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're putting the `:selected` key in the html_options argument attributes.

[Here is the method definition for `collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

Try this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :course_type_id, CourseType.where(:deleted => false), :id, :name, {:selected => @course_template.course_type.name}, {class: 'form-control  m-b' } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<%= f.collection_select :course_type_id, CourseType.where(:deleted => false), :id, :name, { :selected => @course_template.course_type.id }, {class: 'form-control m-b' } %>`

1. The `selected` parameter takes the `value`, and not the `name` of the option.
2. From [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) definition, `selected` option and `html_options` are different params.

For further understanding, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms).