# print two values in collection_select (Rails Forms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, collection-select

For my form, I have this:

```
<%= tag_field.collection_select( :id, Material.order(:name), :id, :name,
      :prompt => "-select-")%>
```

This prints my materials names.
example:

```
Cat 
Cat
```

However, this is not helpful because the materials have the same names.
There is another attribute in the Material record, :color.

I want it to print out this in the dropdown

```
Cat - Brown
Cat - Orange
```

---

How do I go about doing this? I tried calling a method instead, but it doesn't print out the way I want it  to. Here's what I did.

```
View:     
<%= tag_field.collection_select( :id, Material.order(:name), :id, :something,
      :prompt => "-select-")%>

Model:
def something
    materials_array = []
    Material.all.each do |material|
      if material.color == nil
        material.name + '-' + material.size
      else
        materials_array.push(material.name + '-' + material.color)
      end
    end
    materials_array
  end
```

However, the dropdown prints out like this:

```
["Cat - Brown", "Cat - Orange"]
["Cat - Brown", "Cat - Orange"]
```

It prints out twice, with the same values. I think I'm close? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier if you use `select` instead of `collection_select`. Try it:

```
<%= tag_field.select :id, Material.order(:name).map{ |m| [ "#{m.name} - #{m. color}", m.id ] }, {prompt: "-select-"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908171/888278) explains clearly the usage of **collection_select** helper. The method `:name_with_initial` (which corresponds to the method `something` in your code) is explained as:

> ```
> :name_with_initial, # this is name of method that will be called for
> # every row, result will be set as value
>  
> # as a result, every option will be generated by the following rule: 
> # <option value=#{author.id}>#{author.name_with_initial}</option>
> # 'author' is an element in the collection or array
> ```

So if you are getting results twice it means the collection/array has redundant values.