# How to show more attributes in each element of the collection with collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, collection-select

I have this with simple form:

```
= simple_form_for(Note.new, remote: true) do |f|       
  = f.collection_select :dance_id, current_user.dances.includes(:style).all,     
   :id, :style_name, {prompt: "Please select dance"}, {class: "form-control"}
```

Code generated:

```
<select class="form-control" name="note[dance_id]" id="note_dance_id">
    <option value="">Please select dance</option> 
    <option value="39">Adowa Dance (Ghana)</option> 
    <option value="38">Adowa Dance (Ghana)</option> 
    <option value="37">Tango (Argentina)</option>
</select>
```

which works fine as it is displaying all dances by style_name as i want it. But i want to make a difference between two dances and want to also show level and date right next to each dance in the collection because there are many dances with same name bc of the style which is the same!
please help. any better way to do it with simple form helpers?

Comment: Please paste full form's code and also if possible, please rephrase your question. :)

Comment: i did. basically i want to be able to say contemporary dance October 14 (which is the dance.date)

Comment: Is that what you want to display as the text of the select box's option?

Comment: yes thats it! thanks

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms

Comment: yes and still dont understand how to do it!

Comment: Please add the HTML code being generated in your browser

Comment: <select class="form-control" name="note[dance_id]" id="note_dance_id"><option value="">Please select dance</option>
<option value="39">Adowa Dance (Ghana)</option>
<option value="38">Adowa Dance (Ghana)</option>
<option value="37">Tango (Argentina)</option></select>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125762/discussion-between-akash-aggarwal-and-loloso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the discussion, you needed to declare a method in your model's rb file like this:

```
def custom_name
"#{style.name}. #{date}"
end
```

And change the `:style_name` parameter to `:custom_name`