# Changing dropdown content in spree form (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a project that is built on [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) and am trying to concatenate state abbreviations to the state's name in the dropdown when selecting shipping address.

Example: "New York - NY" instead of "New York"

The shipping address form can be found [here](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/address/_form.html.erb) with the code making the state selection dropdown below:

```
 <% if Spree::Config[:address_requires_state] %>
<p class="form-group" id=<%="#{address_id}state" %>>
  <% have_states = !address.country.states.empty? %>
  <%= form.label :state do %>
    <%= Spree.t(:state) %><abbr class='required' title="required" id=<%="#{address_id}state-required"%>>*</abbr>
  <% end %>

  <%== state_elements = [
     form.collection_select(:state_id, address.country.states,
                        :id, :name,
                        {include_blank: true},
                        {class: have_states ? 'form-control required' : 'form-control hidden',
                        disabled: !have_states}) +
     form.text_field(:state_name,
                        class: !have_states ? 'form-control required' : 'form-control hidden',
                        disabled: have_states)
     ].join.gsub('"', "'").gsub("\n", "")
  %>
</p>
  <noscript>
    <%= form.text_field :state_name, class: 'form-control required' %>
  </noscript>
```

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms) post, I thought that `:name` is the method being called to generate the text in each option, but when I changed it to `:abbr` (which should be a property that it has) everything stayed exactly the same. I am pretty sure that my changes are running since when I make other changes it works. How would you change the option text and managing that, how would you get both the name and abbreviation and concatenate them together with a hyphen.

Just as a note: I am using [Deface::Override](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html) to make changes to the code.

Comment: you can easily do it with JQuery on client side..