# Adding records to a 'has_many :through' association using a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my first Rails app and have hit another wall. I have a User model and a Country model. They have a many-to-many relationship, which I join together with a Trip model.

A user can maintain a list of countries that they have been to. On the Country page, I want to have a simple bootstrap button so the current_user can add or remove the country to their list.

I am using a partial that looks like the below to at least render buttons on all the pages.

**_add_remove_countries.html.erb**

```
<% if @user.countries.exists?(@country.id) %>
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Remove Country", class: "btn btn-info" %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>  
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "Add Country", class: "btn btn-info" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried a few different things, with no luck so I have just reverted to the basic structure. I am currently using a form_for, however that is just what has worked best so far, I am not tied to that solution.

Below are my controllers if needed, I have not set up a Trips controller as I am only using it to join the User and Country Model (maybe I need to set one up?).

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @countries = Country.all
  end 

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
      redirect_to user_path
  end


  private 

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


end
```

**countries_controller.rb**

```
class CountriesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :require_user, only: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @countries = Country.all
    @sort = CS.countries.sort_by {|key, value| value}
    @sort = @sort.first @sort.size - 2

  end

  def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion using [collection_select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8908171/938947) (and click link in case you would like to know more about collection_select) to add countries to user while editing user, below is sample code to help (using edit method)

user_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @countries = Country.all
  end 

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # ---> here additional code to edit method
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @countries = Country.all
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to user_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private 

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:username,
          :email,
          :password,
          :password_confirmation,
          :country_ids => [])
        # country_ids is an array that will save data for countries that user have been to
    end
end
```

now this is the fun one, in your **views\user\edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <!--  simple  -->
  <p>Email : </p>
  <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>

  <!-- if you using bootstrap -->
  <div class="row form-group">
    <%= f.label "email", :class => 'control-label col-sm-3' %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- other inputs (password / password_confirmation) -->
  <%= f.collection_select :country_ids, @countries, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true, class: 'form-control' } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however I am looking to keep the function tied to a button on the certain associations page rather than on an edit page. 

The button will be on the specific country page (i.e. /countries/2). For example the page for China will have a button and the user will, depending on the current association, be able to add or remove the association. I have been able to achieve getting the button to display, however, I am struggling to create the association upon selection.