# How to use collection select as a button in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, actionviewhelper

In my form I have a collection_select to be able to select the name of the articles, my problem is that when I select any article nothing happens

```
 <%= form_with url: articles_path do |f| %>
   <%= collection_select(:article, :article_id, @articles, :id, :name ) %>
 <% end %>
```

Of course I would be missing the submit button, but I would like the user to simply select the article name and pass the data to the controller (without having to put a button below collection_select)

I can't find the way, if someone knows about it and can guide me I would be very grateful

Thank you for your time in reading me.

Comment: Nothing happens? What do you mean? May be strong params problem? What do you see in logs?

Comment: I have a form with and I can't send the data to the controller because I don't have a button submit, and that's what I want to do, send data through the collection_select

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907867/can-someone-explain-collection-select-to-me-in-clear-simple-terms

Comment: @ShaherShamroukh Shamroukh I perfectly understand what each of the parameters does (thanks for the link information) but I would like that when the user clicks on an element of the list they can perform an action... I see that with the onchange method it would be a way to do it

Comment: I think there's no way to do it without JS. Plain selects cannot submit the form automatically. Are you ready for a bit of JS code?)))

Comment: I realized a little later :(, I'm thinking of using the onchange event, every time the user selects an option, I still see how I can integrate it. But any JS solution is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have something like this as HTML for your form

```
<form action="/some_path" method="post">
  <select name="article_id" id="article_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

You should put the following JS (given you do not use any JS libs such as `jquery`)

```
const select = document.getElementById('article_id')
select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest()
  const form = event.target.parentElement

  XHR.open(form.getAttribute('method'), form.getAttribute('action'))
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  XHR.send("article_id=" + encodeURIComponent(event.target.value)
})
```

You may also want to add an event listener for `error` and `load` on `XHR` to do some processing depending on was your request successful or not

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for giving me a hand (I was able to learn more about the XMLHttpRequest object) and most of all for helping me.

Many gold badges for you I wish you :D

Comment: @SamuelDaCosta I'm happy if my answer helped. Note, that you probably would want to include `authenticity_token` from your form, if you use `protect_from_forgery` in your controllers